# PHP file not recognizing includes

Tags: php, include, directory, require

So, I have a (presumably) easy problem to fix that is currently triumphing over me.

**My layout starts with the main registration file, in the main directory:**

registration.php

```
<?php

// Include connection to database
require "config/db.php";

// Include website language class
require "classes/website_language.php";

// Include registration class
require "classes/registration.php";

// Include the page
include "views/registration.php";
```

My problem is that classes/registration.php ISN'T including config/db.php or classes/website_language.php, even though I am including those files BEFORE classes/registration.php on the MAIN file.

Since config/db.php and classes/website_language.php is being included on the main registration file before classes/registration.php, shouldn't classes/registration.php be able to pull data from those two included files?

I fixed this by including config/db.php and classes/website_language.php in the classes/registration.php file itself, but I'd prefer to have those includes in the MAIN file, if possible.

Comment: check, registration.php having any bug.

Comment: Please remember to mark the right answer (and give your feedback) to help other people that are (or will be) presented with the same problem

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
require("config/db.php");
require("classes/website_language.php");
require("views/registration.php");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that your problem is that you did not consider that "includes/requires" are relative to the file doing the including.

Let's make an example

**FOLDER STRUCTURE**

```
root/index.php
root/folder1/file1.php
root/folder1/file2.php
```

**THE PROBLEM**

```
index.php

include "folder1/file1.php";

file1.php

include "file2.php";
```

The "include "file2.php";" will be executed by index.php so index.php will search for a file named file2.php in the same folder (root in this case). Of course index.php will not find such file.

**SOLUTION**

```
index.php

include "folder1/file1.php";

file1.php

include dirname(__FILE__) . "/file2.php";
```

So the solution is to work with absolute paths -- and you can mix relatives and absolute paths using dirname(**FILE**), to get the directory that contains the file.